# Persisting Symfony DateIntervalType in doctrine and format it in twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

This question is relative to The [DateIntervalType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/dateinterval.html#input) field type introduced in Symfony 3.2. This field allows the user to select an interval of time in a form.

I would like to know its corresponding doctrine type and how to format it in twig as for example 2 hours and 30 minutes ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doctrine dbal (which is used by doctrine orm) supports dateinterval already. Here is the link:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#dateinterval

Display a dateinterval with twig is really easy, just use the `date` filter which internally use the [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method.